# Is asymmetrically encrypting passwords using JavaScript viable?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I would like to use JavaScript to encrypt a user's password and username when they login (using Ajax). I know there exist several asymmetric encryption libraries for JavaScript. Is this a viable strategy for safely communicating passwords?

I understand that SSL exists, but that is not the question.

Comment: Thanks for the proofreading, Michael Petrotta; I guess my spell checker wasn't on after all :)

Comment: Why don't you just use HTTPS?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Question updated

Comment: @SimpleCoder: But that still doesn’t answer his question.

Comment: Then *why* is it not the question? It's your only option if you want a safe login page.

Comment: @Gumbo: Ok: Cost of SSL certificates, difficulty installing OpenSSL certificates using shared hosting, curiosity

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I was only curious. Based on the feedback I'm getting here, I will end up getting an SSL certificate.

Comment: You can get a self-signed SSL certificate for free. Also see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/where-to-get-an-ssl-certificate-for-personal-website

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Can it be used with GoDaddy Shared Hosting?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, but I'm not that much into SSL.

Comment: And a horrible example of this: http://www.woningnet.nl/ (see source; yuk, it even doesn't accept passwords longer than 8 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It makes no difference if the attacker gets the password or the encrypted password, both are sent to the server "unencrypted", so the encrypted password can be used to login.

JavaScript can't be used for security. You **have** to use HTTPS.

Comment: What if that encryption algorithm was held in a privatized method?

Comment: Why is this necessarily the case? What if I install a SHA1 library (like this one: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.html) and only send hashes of passwords over the network? If this is insecure, then isn't storing SHA1 hashes in databases insecure?

Comment: If the encrypted packet contained a timestamp, it would limit the time which the encrypted password was valid. Even better first request a token from the server which is added to the password before encryption, each token would only be able to be used once.

Comment: @Greg Agnew: It doesn't matter how you classify it. The encryption algorithm must be employed on the user's client machine. This means that it is publicly readable. You can't stop that, even if you send your method through an obfuscation process.

Comment: The encryption algorithm isn't relevant. The attacker can used the encrypted password - no matter how it was encrypted - to login.

Comment: @Zach Rattner - If the method accepts an already hashed password and compares it against what is in the database, then it is vulnerable to a replay attack. Storing a hash in a database isn't insecure because the input is hashed THEN compared. In OPs case, the hash is accepted as is and compared.

Comment: @Zach Rattner: if you pass the same token every time to the server it does not matter if the attacker has you password or the hash of the password they can authenticate with your server. So sending a hash of the password may prevent certain types of hackers getting your password (see salting and rainbow charts) but will not prevent them authenticating if all you require for authentication is the hash of the password.

Comment: @RoToRa: Handling the password only as hashes is a courtesy to your users; it is to prevent attackers from getting the user's password as a plain text. Many people uses the same password or similar passwords for multiple website, and if your website is hacked, having only the hashes eliminates the possibility of you being responsible for divulging the user's password for twenty other websites, so in such unfortunate events, only your website will be affected. That said, it's true that using hashes does not increase the security to your own website.

Comment: @ Joel Etherton, what if I hash the password again in the database?

Comment: Sorry, this is just not correct. It is perfectly possible to use Javascript to implement a zero-knowledge-proof algorithm that will be safe against a passive attacker.

Comment: @Zach Then it remains the case that the first hash of the password is, effectively, the password. An attacker can intercept that and send it, and you have no way to tell if they had the original password, or just the hash.

Comment: @Rasmus Unfortunately, an entirely passive attacker is an unlikely threat model for a webapp. In most situations where the attacker can listen - eg, open wifi - they can also interfere.

Comment: WRONG!! If the user shares the password aginst several systems, altought you can protect your system **at least** you can protect the user's password.
If you aren't using HTTPS maybe you're security is not critical. But the user maybe uses the same password for the bank account, or mail.

Comment: Using the same password for Soapy Britches dot com and your bank is *your* problem. I totally understand the general sentiment here, that handling a user's password means being responsible and considerate with the trust they are extending to you. But some guys website API or a cool new photo share site is *not* my bank. I expect my bank to be hardcore locked down and certified up to the ceiling.

Answer (score 5):

Step one: don't trust people on the internet, I will propose a weak algorithm to ensure I can break it.

Step two: Don't design your own algorithm, or implement anyone else's in a production system until you have a PHD in computer security

Encryption is not enough to protect against replay attacks, if an attacker get the encrypted password, it is of as much use to them as an unencrypted password if it is enough to authenticate.

I would suggest:

1. User enters there password
2. Client requests token from server
3. Server returns a unique random token, and stores this against the users session (keyed by cookie stored on the server)
4. The client encrypts the password + token using your public key and passes this to the server.
5. The server decrypts this, using your private key, and checks the token matches this session, has not been used before and is no older then 30 seconds.
6. The server checks the hash of the password matches the hash of the users password as stored in the datastore.

All data transmitted will still be visible, so the users will not gain any privacy ( as they would in https). Your encryption algorithm, encryption implementation and public key will be public. This is the case for a large amount of current cryptolagy, a large number of algorithms are designed to be secure with the attacker knowing this.

This will not protect against any keylogger or spyware attack, as they will target before the password is encrypted.

I have no knowledge of implementations of asymmetric encryption implemented in javascript but there is nothing fundamentally insecure in this approach.

Comment: 30 seconds? What if I have to look up my password, because I made it so strong I can't remember it by heart?

Comment: So, based on your first point, should I trust the system you proposed?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Nope :) I have an interest insecurity and I believe this will make it more secure, but I'm just evil bob tricking you. In seriousness I believe what I say is correct but you only have my word on it, and I may be mistaken.

Comment: @David Waters: That's what I thought :). Really, then, you are actually Eve?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: You get the user to enter their password before you request the token from the server, so the 30 seconds is just network latency and encryption time. No time waiting for the user. I have clarified my answer.

Comment: @David Waters: even if you do have a PhD, you need to check your professor's PhD and your professor's professor's PhD and so on to make sure what they are teaching is actually secure. And then you need to check if those professors may have any hidden motivation to deliberately teach insecure schemes.

Comment: I like how having a PhD is the proof that one's cryptography is secure. Like, I probably have a better handle on how to tell if an algorithm is secure than most guys with PhD's. Getting an edumication from a school doesn't imply that you're now an expert and have mastered the subject.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an algorithm such as the [Secure Remote Password protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) to provide a zero knowledge proof that you know the password. An eavesdropper will not be able to use this to replicate your login. However, beware of an active attacker that replaces your Javascript code with something that transmits the password directly to him.

There are several Javascript implementations of SRP:

- [srp-js](http://code.google.com/p/srp-js/)
- [Javascript Crypt Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipperz)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd have much to gain from doing this, certainly less than the performance hit such a mathematically intensive piece of JavaScript would impose.  If you're using this to encrypt a piece of data before sending it to the server via HTTP, then while you'll have protected a hacker from discovering exactly what the password is, you wouldn't have stopped them from gaining access by simply running a replay attack with the same piece of encrypted data you've sent.

The only viable way to protect a form submission is to use HTTPS.  I know setting HTTPS up is a hassle, what with the certificates that only work in one domain and all that, but if the information really is critical then it's a better investment of your time than trying to do encryption in JavaScript.

Comment: Math in javascript is actually pretty damn fast already, javascript is considered slow because most often it is associated with the hard-to-abstract and complex process of DOM manipulation. See [this demo](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/demo/) (symmetric encryption).

Answer (score 1):

There are still problems with this model because you are still just passing text across the connection. Without some measure of a date in the encryption/decryption/comparation process you still end up with the potential for a replay attack.

Even beyond the man-in-the-middle attack that would still be prevalent, you'd still have the fact that your algorithm for encryption and public key would be out there. If someone were to get a hold of an encrypted password they would then have a permanent source from which to brute force that password just as easily.

Comment: Better encrypt the hecking heck out of it then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from a non-authenticate communication you're always at risk of man-in-the-middle.

Anyway, transmit a salted and hashed password is **always better** than transmit the plain password. Because maybe your log-in system is weak, but **at least you aren't sharing the user's password** (which can be shared with another system, **maybe used for bank account**).

Also, don't store that value, but salt-and-hash it again.

If you also use asymmetrically encryption you add protection against eavesdropping. But again, not against man-in-the-middle.